# Не открывается бинарный файл в Си. Debug Assertion Failed: stream != nullptr

Tags: c, файлы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]   Ну вообщем, функция load_fileSTUD не видит файл "Stud_Info" который я создал в папке "practuka"

```
void save_fileSTUD(Student* Stud, int num) {
        FILE* f = fopen("C:\\practuka\\Stud_Info", "wb");
        fwrite(&num, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            fwrite(&Stud[i], sizeof(Student), 1, f);
        fclose(f);
    }
    void load_fileSTUD() {
        FILE* f;
        f = fopen("C:\\practuka\\Stud_Info", "rb");
        if (f == NULL) {
            printf("Файл не знайдено!\n");
            return;
        }
        fread(&num, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        Student* new_Stud = (Student*)malloc(num * sizeof(Student));
        fread(new_Stud, sizeof(Student), num, f);
        fclose(f);
        free(Stud);
        Stud = new_Stud;
    }
```

Comment: Разрешение файла. Если это не поможет, можно посмотреть код ошибки в `errno`.

Comment: разрешение файла txt.

Comment: Я про то, что в путь к файлу нужно поставить разрешение файла.

Comment: спасибо,помогло

Comment: @TRIGGERED, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: @TRIGGERED лучше для бинарных файлов использовать разрешение `.bin`. Это никак не повлияет на работоспособность, но для других людей будет очевидно, что это не текст, а именно бинарник.

Comment: Вот так ошибка, везде имелось в виду **расширение** файла, не разрешение

Answer (score 1):

Путь к файлу обязан содержать расширение файла, если файл таковое имеет:

```
FILE* f = fopen("C:\\practuka\\Stud_Info.txt", "wb");
```

Вместо:

```
FILE* f = fopen("C:\\practuka\\Stud_Info", "wb");
```